# GitHub Action: Deploy output of vue-cli-service build to Azure App Service

Tags: npm, yaml, github-actions, vue-cli, azure-appservice

I'm using a GitHub action to deploy to Azure App Service, and, although the npm build succeeds, I cannot figure out how to get the output of that build to be deployed along with the output of the .NET build.

As you can see in my workflow file, for the .NET build, I specified  `--output ./deploy` and then at the bottom, that is deployed via `package: './deploy'`

However I don't know how to get the npm build output into `'./deploy'`. Currently, the npm build places the output into `ClientApp/dist`, according to vue.config.js.

Vue config relevant line: `outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "ClientApp/dist")`

Entire action workflow file:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build-all:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1       
      env:
        DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '5.0.x'
    - run: dotnet build ./source/trunk/my/project.csproj --output ./deploy
        
    - name: Frontend build
      working-directory: ./source/trunk/my/project
      run: |
        npm install
        npm install @vue/cli-service
        npx -p @vue/cli vue-cli-service build --mode development
        
    - name: Azure login
      uses: azure/login@v1.1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET}}
        enable-AzPSSession: false
        
    - name: Azure deploy
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with: 
        app-name: my-app-name
        package: './deploy'
```